# Unable to manage existing IP address ranges in IPAM after its installation

Tags: windows, dhcp, ipam

I have an environment with one Windows server that is running as DC, DNS and DHCP server. In my LAN, I have one network: 192.168.10.0/24.

On another server, I've installed Microsoft IPAM server (as a Windows server feature). I successfully provisioned and retrieved all data from both DNS and DHCP servers to IPAM. Now I want to edit the existing DHCP range of 192.168.10.0/24 network directly from IPAM console. But when I open the "Edit IP Address Range..." window, nearly all fields are grayed out:
[Window when editing the range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzLgS.png).

My guess is that it has something to do with a "Managed by Service" option and that it is set to MS DHCP, not IPAM. Am I right? If so, is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already done the provisioning?

`Invoke-IpamServerProvisioning -WidSchemaPath "D:\database" -ProvisioningMethod Automatic -GpoPrefix IPAM1`
This cmdlet will provision IPAM on ipam1.contoso.com. As a part of provisioning, this cmdlet will provision IPAM to use Windows Internal database.
The cmdlet will create a new IPAM database at D:\database, create roles, and prepare IPAM for use.
IPAM will be configured to use Group Policy to provision the managed servers. Read the product documentation for details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I did not by this command, however when I execute this exact dommand, I get message "IPAM is already provisioned on this server.".